# R-function If statement for passing on variables

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I'm trying to write an `if` statement in a function. It's for the `x` variable that either can be a couple of the variables from the dataset or all of the variables in the `data.frame`, like:  (Both `X` and `Y` are given like column names)

```
f <- function(y,x,data){
    if (x=="all"){something<-y+2}else{something<-y+5}
}
```

I get the error:

> "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: Please provide a working example / sample data set.

Comment: That's usually the error you get when you need to use `ifelse` (which is vectorized) instead of `if` (which is not), but it's hard to say without data/context.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to address how the logical comparison works. This may help you solve the problem.

If you use logical operation without `if` statement, you will get this.

```
c("a","b","c","a") == "a"
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

However, if you use the logical operation within "if" statement, it works differently. It uses only the first element like this example.

```
if(c("a","b","c","a") == "b"){print("exist")}else{print("not exist")}
[1] "not exist"

if(c("a","b","c","a") == "a"){print("exist")}else{print("not exist")}
[1] "exist"
```

I assume you may need to use `length()` or `%in%`.